# Как оптимизировать код для юнити?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть код, который показывает определённый текст. Если игрок не был в комнате, то пишется "???".

Как можно это оптимиизировать?

```cs
else if (item == "bathroom" && PlayerPrefs.GetInt("bathroomOpenTime") == 1){_textInfo.text = "Войти в ванную";}
else if (item == "bathroom" && PlayerPrefs.GetInt("bathroomOpenTime") == 0){_textInfo.text = "???";}

else if (item == "bedroom" && PlayerPrefs.GetInt("bedroomOpenTime") == 1){_textInfo.text = "Войти в спальню";}      
else if (item == "bedroom" && PlayerPrefs.GetInt("bedroomOpenTime") == 0){_textInfo.text = "???";}      

else if (item == "kitchen" && PlayerPrefs.GetInt("kitchenOpenTime") == 1){_textInfo.text = "Войти на кухню";} 
else if (item == "kitchen" && PlayerPrefs.GetInt("kitchenOpenTime") == 0){_textInfo.text = "???";} 

else if (item == "basement" && PlayerPrefs.GetInt("basementOpen") == 0){_textInfo.text = "???";}
else if (item == "basement" && PlayerPrefs.GetInt("basementOpen") == 1){_textInfo.text = "Войти в подвал";}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Составляем карту (словарь) с данными, где будут данные представленные в виде `string` => `string`. Схематично будет так:

```
'bathroom' => 'ванную',
'bedroom' => 'спальню',
'kitchen' => 'кухню',
'basement' => 'подвал'
```

Т.к. везде есть слово `Time`, то для `basement` лучше тоже так сделать.

В итоге весь год можно будет сократить до такого:

```
if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt($"{item}OpenTime") == 1)
    _textInfo.text = $"Войти в {dictionary[item]}";
else
    _textInfo.text = "???";
```

---

Конечно можно ещё сделать доп проверку о наличии вообще такого ключа и значения по ключу для словаря, типа `dictionary.TryGetValue(....)`, а потом использовать if/else